# Is there a way to build SQL queries similar to how DOMDocument builds HTML document?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, domdocument

Is there a way to build SQL queries that is similar to `DOMDocument` for HTML pages?

Too many possibilities for syntax errors here:

```
$query = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table;
if ($condition) 
  $query .= "WHERE status > 1";
```

Is there third party or stock way to build queries similar to `DOMDocument`?

Comment: Yes, there are several DB-Classes available. I use [MysqliDB](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class), but there are for sure many others.

Comment: As an illustration, you seem to have a syntax error in your example query.

Comment: Always search stackoverflow first before posting a question. You are not the first person to face this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using plain sql queries I usually don't use multi-line concats as they lead to a syntax error as you have above. When adding multiple lines for one part, I place the connector (comma for field lists, join for from, and/or for where) at the beginning of the new line.

```
$query = "SELECT ".$fields;
$query .= " FROM ".$table;
if ($condition) {
  $query .= "WHERE status > 1";
}
```

For some parts using arrays with join() comes in handy:

```
$conditions = array();
$conditions[] = "status > 1";
// Later on
if ($conditions) {
  // Depending on your intention, you can use AND or OR here:
  $query .= "WHERE ".join(' AND ', $conditions);
}
```

But there are many libraries to build queries in an object oriented manner. Last *I* tested is doctrine's query builder.

Comment: Any names for this libraries?